# Windows Forms - adding an empty field to a data bind combobox list

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, data-binding, ado.net

I'm having a `combo`  DropDownList which i fill with data like this:

```
cboTypeOfMaterial.DataSource = (from tom in context.MaterialTypes
                                where tom.IsActive == true
                                select tom.Name).Distinct().ToList();
```

The problem is that I use this DropDownList for search and I want to have one empty row or whatever, just one extra row which I can use to leave the list empty if the user don't want to include this data in a certain search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
IList<String> materialTypes = (from tom in context.MaterialTypes
                                where tom.IsActive == true
                                select tom.Name).Distinct().ToList();
materialTypes.Insert(0, "-- Please Select --");
cboTypeOfMaterial.DataSource = materialTypes;
```

Comment: Thanks, gonna use this, seems most clear to me even thou it's the same as `Gian ACuna`'s answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = (from tom in context.MaterialTypes
            where tom.IsActive == true
            select tom.Name).Distinct().ToList();

list.Insert(0, "");
cboTypeOfMaterial.DataSource = list;
```

This adds a blank item into the list.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could just add an empty element to your list first then add the items from your context

```
Example:

cboTypeOfMaterial.DataSource = new string[] { string.Empty }
                               .Concat(from tom in context.MaterialTypes
                                       where tom.IsActive == true
                                       select tom.Name).Distinct().ToList();
```